# Unchecked checkbox returning null value

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, cordova

I have a set of checkboxes which when checked they pass the value as 1, otherwise they pass the value as 0.  However, instead of sending the value of the unchecked checkboxes as '0', the value being sent is 'NULL'.

I have the following JS code in place that should set the value to 0/1 accordingly, however still the value is sent as NULL.  Is there anything that can be done to make sure that the value passed in case of an unchecked checkbox is 0?

```
$('#cb1, #cb2, #cb3, #cb4').on('click', function ()
    $(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0);
});
```

**UPDATED**
Here is my html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb4" id="cb4" value="1" checked />
```

They are all checked by default.

If one of them is unchecked, MySQL is reporting the following error:
0SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ColumnName' cannot be null.

This is because the columns are set to set not to be Null.  And even though I have set the default value to 0, once I click on the submit button I still get the error.  I tried to remove the Not NULL property however rather than prefilling the value as 0, the input was NULL in the database.

Comment: Could you also add your html?

Comment: Consider changing your HTML like this: `<input type="hidden" name="cb1" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="1" checked />` .

Comment: this should work but you are missing an `{` in you javascript... here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5vS3S/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If a checkbox is unchecked, it doesn't get sent, so setting it's value to 0 if it isn't checked isn't going to help - it will always return NULL.

There are two ways to fix this easily:

1) Assume a NULL in the PHP params means the checkbox is unchecked. If the checkbox doesn't always exist on the page, this could be problematic. By the sounds of it, there is a variable number of checkboxes, so this probably won't work.

2) Add a hidden input that has the same name as the checkbox with the value of 0 **BEFORE** the checkbox. If the checkbox is unchecked, the hidden field value will be used, if it is checked the checkbox value will be used.

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox_1" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="1">
```

Note: If your names are in an array form (ie they have square brackets in them), this won't work, as the hidden fields will increment the array count as well.

Comment: Actually, if your names are in an array form, simply include the key for the index in the brackets.  You will then be able to set input names like arrays.

Comment: @axiom82 you didn't get it. Yeah, you can do that, but when a checkbox is checked, you will add TWO elements to the destination array, so you will soon lose correspondence of indexes to chekboxes and you won't have any useful information indicating if the index of the array refers to a checked or an unchecked item. You can do some easy postprocessing of the resulting array to avoid this, though.

Comment: Great solution. Helped me a lot, specially the second one. Thanks!

Comment: what is the case if i have to collect multiple checkbox values Linke <input type="checkbox" name="slides_data[enable_content][]" style="min-width: 20px;"  />

Comment: i think that should work ideal for missing will get 0 and for check i will get on thanks--update its not working its adding another since its array

Comment: @Azmatkarim Put a number in the square brackets - you'll have to manage the incrementing - just make sure the hidden field and the checkbox have the same index.

ie

<input type="hidden" name="checkbox[0]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox[1]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" value="1">

Comment: Thanks @Myles Eftos, actually there are lot of section which contains checkbox and they can be deleted and updated in any order so i have to re-index all the checkbox, so i switched to select element with 2 option YES and NO that is working great. and thanks for your answer that was something new i learnt :)

Comment: What a great sollution, Thanks

Comment: Interesting ... Its 2021, I'm using Google Chrome "Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (x86_64)" on a Mac and the "hidden/checkbox" solution works, EXCEPT that I had to list the checkbox BEFORE the hidden input. Apparently, only the first "name" sent is sent, so the hidden input is sent if the checkbox is not. IMHO, the correct solution is for a checkbox always to send a value that represents the state of the box ...

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could use the checked selector to get the state of a checkbox. When it is checked, the length contains something greater than 0, e.G.:

```
$('#id:checked').length
```

So you don't need to set the value of the checkbox element to 0...

Answer (score 0):

**CHANGE YOUR SCRIPT LIKE THIS. HOPE IT HELPS.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cb1, #cb2, #cb3, #cb4').click(function(){
        $(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because if you have de-selected the checkbox, the value is null, because it has no value. Check this example from w3cschools:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox

If you have selected nothing, the value does not get submitted. But if you selected something, its value will be submitted.

If you really want true/false value, you need to trick it.. so send the state of the checked attribute will do the trick.

```
$('#id:checked').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , it may help you. Assume your form is like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Active</td>
  <td><?php echo form_checkbox('active',set_value('active',$student->active),TRUE); ?>  </td>
</tr>
```

Now you set your codeigniter controller like this:

```
// Set up the form
$rules = $this->student_m->rules;
$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

// Process the form
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
   $data = $this->student_m->array_from_post(array(
           'active',
           'name'
   ));

   // checking is checkbox is checked or not
   ($data['active'] == TRUE)?($data['active'] = 1) : ($data['active'] = 0);

   $this->student_m->save($data, $id);
   redirect('admin/student');
}
```