# How to get unchecked checkbaox values in Laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel-5

There are 4 check boxes with the same name in the view, and when I get the values in the laravel(php) controller with that name, I am supposed to get an array. But I am only getting the values of the check boxes which are checked, even I am not getting zero or null in place of unchecked checkboxes.

```
<div id="action1" name="action1[]">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkAction1[]" >
                            <select id="a1" class="form-control actionSelect" name="action1[]" >
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Action Name</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="form-control catSelect" name="cat1[]">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Category Type</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                        <div id="action2" name="action1[]">
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="checkAction1[]" >
                            <select class="form-control actionSelect" name="action1[]" >
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Action Name</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="form-control catSelect" name="cat1[]">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Category Type</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                        <div id="action3" name="action1[]">
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="checkAction1[]" >
                            <select class="form-control actionSelect" name="action1[]" >
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Action Name</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="form-control catSelect" name="cat1[]">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Category Type</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                        <div id="action4" name="action1[]">
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="checkAction1[]" >
                            <select class="form-control actionSelect" name="action1[]" >
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Action Name</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="form-control catSelect" name="cat1[]">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Category Type</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
```

Controller:

```
$checkboxArray=$request['checkAction1'];
```

Its only giving checked check boxes.

Could any one help on this. Thank you.

Comment: What you want with unchecked values. show some more codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unchecked checkbox returning null value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067215/unchecked-checkbox-returning-null-value)

Comment: If you include the key in the checkbox name, you still won't get unchecked entries, but the ones that **are** set will have the correct indexes. For example `<input type="checkbox" name="checkAction1[0]" >`, `<input type="checkbox" name="checkAction1[1]" >`, `<input type="checkbox" name="checkAction1[2]" >` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

in the controller, modify the request

```
if (!$request->has('field')) {
    $request->merge(['field' => 0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct example with `hidden` input is:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="checkAction1[]" value="0" >
<input type="checkbox"  name="checkAction1[]" value="1" >
```

Comment: Doesn't it still have the same problem, that because the field is an array, there will be an indeterminate number of entries; a single `0` if the checkbox is unchecked but a `0` and a `1` if it's checked? This syntax only works for fields without the `[]`.

Answer (score -3):

Add a hidden input for the checkbox

`<input type="checkbox"  name="checkAction1[]" value="Yes" >
<input type="hidden"  name="checkAction1[]" value="No" >`

Comment: The checkboxes are sent as arrays. Surely this will result in `$checkboxArray` looking like `["Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"]` if you tick the first and the fourth box, for example?

Comment: Well unfortunately if you put hidden after checkbox you'll always get `"No"` in the array.