# Laravel edit blade checkbox array issue

Tags: arrays, laravel, checkbox, crud, edit

**My Problem** I can't get my dynamic checkboxes to save properly in from my **edit.blade**, they only work if the values are 1, if an unchecked checkbox is submitted via hidden field it will overwrite the next set of checkbox checked values.

**My Code**
I have a crud resource that takes orders, the form in the **create.blade** itself has a bunch of dynamic fields that add a new product to the order via 'add-new' button that clones the product fields.

Part of that form is a bunch of days checkboxes that work fine and are stored correcly.

**Where I'm Getting Stuck**
I've made an **edit.blade** to be used to correct any mistakes that would be made while creating an order.

To call back the section that refers to the dates checkboxes I've used the following blade syntax (I know its different from create, mainly due to me trying to fix the problem)

```
@foreach($orders as $orderkey => $order)
@foreach($days as $day)
    {{ Form::hidden($day.'[]', 0, array('id'=> $day.'_hidden_'.$orderkey, 'class' => 'is-checkradio')) }}
    {{ Form::checkbox($day.'[]', 1, $order->{$day}, array('id'=> $day.'_'.$orderkey, 'class' => 'is-checkradio')) }}
    <label for="<?php echo $day.'_'.$orderkey; ?>"><?php echo $day; ?></label>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

**OrderController - Update**
I've had to use the following in my controller to get the fields to update however whenever a checkbox is left unchecked it will overwrite the next checked value.

```
$customer = Customer::find($id);
    foreach($customer->orders as $key => $order){
        $Monday[] = $request->Monday[$key];
    };

 $updates = array(
     'Monday' => $Monday,
 );

foreach($updates['orders'] as $k => $update){
    $update_order->Monday = $updates['Monday'][$k];
    $update_order->save();
    };
```

Comment: Can you provide a smaller, simpler example for us to review? There's a lot of code here.

Comment: I'll cut down the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to fix it from [Unchecked checkbox returning null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067215/unchecked-checkbox-returning-null-value)

I needed to add my $orderkey to the name []

So in the end this worked:

```
@foreach($days as $day)
        {{ Form::hidden($day.'['.$orderkey.']', null, array('id'=> $day.'_hidden_'.$orderkey, 'class' => 'is-checkradio')) }}
        {{ Form::checkbox($day.'['.$orderkey.']', 1, $order->{$day}, array('id'=> $day.'_'.$orderkey, 'class' => 'is-checkradio')) }}
        <label for="<?php echo $day.'_'.$orderkey; ?>"><?php echo $day; ?></label>        
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
foreach($customer->orders as $key => $order){
    $Monday[] = $request->Monday[$key];
};
```

Is creating an array where if the existing data is true **and** the new data is true, save it. Otherwise delete it. That means any checkboxes that have been *deselected* will be captured, but any *newly checked* checkboxes won't be. Is this your intention?

Why not just do:

```
$updates = array(
    'Monday' => $request->Monday,
);
```

I may not have fully understood your question so please comment and/or amend the Q if you need to clarify further,

Comment: Added an answer with a bit more info