# Array of checkbox with same name , Unchecked checkbox returning null value in python and flask

Tags: python, jquery, html, list, flask

I am using an array of checkboxes. When checked they're giving **"on"** value but when unchecked it's giving a `null`.

If I have 4 checkboxes in that if I checked 2 and 2 is unchecked array gives me 2 values. See below image.

How I can get 4 values, I tried type ="hidden" with same name but it's not worked. Also I tried [Unchecked checkbox returning null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067215/unchecked-checkbox-returning-null-value)

**HTML**

```
                    `<form action="{{ url_for('desc') }}" method="POST">
                           <div id="items" class="col-sm-12">
                           <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4" class="checkbox">
                                <p><label>&nbsp;</label></p>
                                  <label class="col-sm-4">MR: <input type="checkbox"  style="width: 20px;height: 20px;" name="mr"  ></label>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
                        </div>
                     </form>`
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addItem(){
var html = '<div class="form-group"> <div class="col-sm-8"><label>Name:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"></div><div class="col-sm-4" class="checkbox"><p><label>&nbsp;</label></p><label class="col-sm-4">MR: <input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;" name="mr"></label></div>'
$('#items').append(html);
}
```

I used javascript for adding item dynamically

**python**

```
`@app.route('/desc', methods=['POST'])
  def desc():
   if request.method == "POST":

    # name = request.form['name']
    items = request.form.getlist('name')
    mr = request.form.getlist('mr')

    print(items)
    print(mr)




    for (x, y) in zip(items, mr):
        print(x)
        print(y)

    return redirect(url_for('Index'))`
```

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BfSV.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICSIL.png)

see image.In first image there is 4 **checkbox** and **name**. I filled name in 2 fields and checked 2 checkbox. But see **output** image in that I get 4 values in name array and only 2 values in checkbox. But there is 4 checkbox

Comment: sorry but your question is not clear at all. can you give more details and show more code?

Comment: @Tobin , when checkbox  in not ticked its no giving data in python flask. see image.In first image there is 4 checkbox in that i ticked on 3 , now see second image its giving only 3 value in array, but there is 4 checkbox

Comment: Exactly we need to see how you wrote your code, to test it eventually, to know where the problem comes from. In the current state we will have to guess where the problem comes from, which is difficult... Please add your code, if possible a complete example that we can test.

Comment: @Tobin , now I added my whole code. Checkbox not sending 4 values